# Сбросились переводы в окне сниппета

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, сниппеты

Сбросились переводы кнопок

1. Сохранить и вставить
2. Добавить внешнюю библиотеку

А также пункты:

1. показать консоль
2. скрыть сниппет

Ниже приведен скриншот показывающий дефекты

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну бывает такое )

Comment: @NickVolynkin, да-да, это все потому, что кто-то решил сниппеты покорячить :)

Comment: я твой сниппет тулбар шатал!

Comment: @NickVolynkin, кстати `hide snippet` так и не поправили :)